# find the xnor bits of two binary input c++

Tags: c++, binary

I am doing the xnor gate using c++ , i am able to code to find the answer by using recursion function,however the answer bits are in reversed orders ,because i compare two binary input by using modulo which chop of the last digit and compare ,if equal output one , otherwise output 0 , my question is how to reverse the answer into correct order.
int xnor(int x, int y) { //function to apply xnor

```
if (x > 0) {

    int reminder1 = x % 10;
    int reminder2 = y % 10;

    if (reminder1 == reminder2) {

        cout<<1;

    }
    else {

        cout<<0;
    }
     return xnor(x / 10, y / 10);

}
```

}

let's say if i input 110001   and  101110
it will display 000001  instead of 100000

Comment: why not just `return ~(x^y)`

Comment: @Zinki because OP encodes data convoluted way - decimal binary

Comment: 1. Fix your code formatting 2. Explain why you have to encode data such ineffective and convoluted way.

Answer (score 2):

Fix for your function is simple, just put recursive call before your output instead of after. Also you are missing return statement for else case of `x > 0`. But that is not proper solution. Proper one is to normally encode data, not in convoluted binary decimal. Yes standard streams missing input/output of binary data but you can use `std::bitset` for that or write a converter from binary string to int and vice versa, which is trivial. Then you function would become trivial as well and would not require any recursion, as binary operations are native for most CPUs:

```
int xnor(int x, int y)
{
    return ~(x^y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add a 3rd string parameter (the answer so far) and in the last iteration you would want to reverse the string before couting it.
You can give the third parameter a default case empty xnor(int x, int y, string s = "") so you don't have to give it a value when you call it the first time.